# Angular.JS 404 page Single Page App

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to make a "404 - page not found" tutorial for a Single page app in angularJS.

Or even better explain how this can be achieved.

There doesn't seem to be much on the internet regarding this.

Comment: What router are you using and what version of Angular?

Comment: use the route system to redirect to a 404 page

Comment: Do yo mean route not found or template not found?

Comment: templateURL Not found Nikhil

Comment: I'm using AngularJS v1.3.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not look at it as 404 page.

In your SPA (Single page app) you could make multiple API calls that independtly update widgets on a dashboard, which 9 out of 10 are successful (200's) and one fails (404), in that case you do not want to redirect users.

As **David Barker** said you have a **`otherwise`** that is a catch-all page.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.template.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
      }).
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.template.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

So if a user enters a incorrect route then go to the dashboard, the only problem is feedback:

1: You need a messaging service to feedback that the actual API 404 has had an error response and that can be managed using a interceptor, directive and model.

2: You can feedback a error message by using a run method and the same  directive and model that look for $routeChangeError then adds a error message

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

In an Angular SPA using the native router, if a route is not found it will hit the `$routeProvider.otherwise()` method thus loading a view for a route that would have typically 404'ed if delivered from a server.

```
angular.app('application', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

        // If route is not configured go to 404 route
        $routeProvider.otherwise('/404');

        $routeProvider.when('404', { /* route configuration */ });

    });
```

The only disadvantage here is that the URL pushstate is also changed, however that would have typically happened anyway if redirected to a custom 404 by a server.

Comment: So if the templateURL isn't found and returns a 404 error this script will then redirect them to a 404 page

Comment: No, not in that case. If the templateUrl isn't found Angular will error. You can theoretically catch that error and redirect to a 404. Can you post up the template loading code you have?